# cvSaveImage not able to save image on changing -prefix to "a" in examples/detector.c

Tags: opencv, darknet

I want to save the image on a running video for the command `./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights <video_file>`. So I changed the value of -prefix parameter to "a" in examples/detector.c to save image instead of streaming the video

```
Loading weights from yolo.weights...Done!
video file: /home/ubuntu/VID_20170602_164011.3gp
save_image_jpg(): a_00000000.jpg

FPS:0.0
Objects:

save_image_jpg(): a_00000001.jpg

FPS:0.0
Objects:

refrigerator: 26%
person: 40%
save_image_jpg(): a_00000002.jpg

FPS:0.0
Objects:

refrigerator: 36%
person: 88%
refrigerator: 26%
save_image_jpg(): a_00000003.jpg
```

But the jpg images are not saved in my system. I am using ubuntu as OS. Help is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

The code changing the value from prefix 0 to "a" actually works. Just some file permissions was supposed to be given. Also you can change the image directory path in function save_image_jpg

> sprintf(buff, "your_img_path/%s.jpg", name);

Later run the following command to convert the images to Video

> ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i your_img_path/a_%08d.jpg -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p video_name.mp4